# The problem with interfaces that extends the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want classes that implement the Observer interface to also implement the Comparable interface, how can I do this?

```
interface Comparable<T> {
    equals: (item: T) => boolean;
}

interface Observer extends Comparable<Observer> {
    notify: () => void
}

class TestA implements Observer {
    private name = '';

    equals = (item: TestA) => {
        return this.name === item.name
    }

    notify = () => {}
}

class TestB implements Observer {
    private name = '';

    equals = (item: TestB) => {
        return this.name === item.name
    }

    notify = () => {}
}
```

Error:

> TS2416: Property 'equals' in type 'TestA' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Observer'.   Type '(item: TestA) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(item: Observer) => boolean'.     Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.       Property 'name' is missing in type 'Observer' but required in type 'TestA'.

But, TestA implements the Observer interface why are they not compatible?

Of course, I can write like this:

```
class TestA implements Observer {
    private name = '';

    equals = (item: Observer) => {
        return this.name === item.name
    }

    notify = () => {}
}
```

But then I get such an error, and besides, this is not entirely correct, because I want to compare only objects of this class:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Observer'.

How to do it right?
"typescript": "^3.9.2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) instead of generics?  Your `Comparable` and `Observer` would become:

```
interface Comparable {
    equals: (item: this) => boolean;
}

interface Observer extends Comparable {
    notify: () => void
}
```

meaning that object of type `X` that extends `Comparable` needs to have an `equals()` method taking a value of type `X`.  Note that this implies that `Comparable` doesn't act like a normal type in terms of substitutability and inheritance.  Generally if you have `interface B extends A {...}` then you should be able to use a `B` anywhere you require an `A`:

```
interface A {
    someMethod(x: A): void;
}

interface B extends A {
    someOtherMethod(x: B): void;
}

declare const b: B;
const a: A = b; // okay
```

But this will not work for `Comparable`:

```
declare const o: Observer;
const c: Comparable = o; // error! equals is incompatible
```

---

Anyway, this definition of `Comparable` will allow your implementations as-is:

```
class TestA implements Observer {
    private name = '';

    equals = (item: TestA) => {
        return this.name === item.name
    }

    notify = () => { }
}

class TestB implements Observer {
    private name = '';

    equals = (item: TestB) => {
        return this.name === item.name
    }

    notify = () => { }
}
```

But again, you'll run into issues if you try to treat `TestA` or `TestB` as an `Observer`:

```
function takeObservers(o1: Observer, o2: Observer) {
    o1.equals(o2);    
}
takeObservers(new TestA()); // error
```

So you might decide that you actually don't want to constrain `equals()` this way.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHOU4BGANigN4CwAUMjchAI4CucRAzgFzIAUwkmnYABbBWASmQBeAHzIC6dCTggA3FQC+VKqEixEKAPIFW0AG7Q6AD0ggAJqzRZc+YmSq1kIdGGAwAnpy5xaWQTdGAbdU1KBCI4VnsAFQhWMABBZGAcEkwIcHtDYygzKGQKalpsKGATOEgPOBzJZAByZtVKN1oGZjYmnj5OJJTUoJky93coCDBGKBBkIREAOhAGlAkNjL4Vtc6aDQ7ymk9vPz7R0uQDg6oYuMTksAAhDKyIHLzkAtNzcYqqmp1VaNCQtNpRdzdFj2UH9d6DR5PC5-CbIKYzOYLYSsHYgza8d64iB7K4Q2gnHy+c6SMakyhqZBRbTQeBIZDpFHIVhYCAAWWmgnQNi4Fk4I04oXC7QZTPALL0yBeECsuTs7NKJO5OX0Qmg-KEQpFnCRErCNmlURsEDuU2QCHQIBSsmN7XtjrAyDgYqaBGUyAA9P7kOgANZwXyW62xW1up3oTjfIrQV0Op0ITgYHB4QgkJroP2BuhQKDoKAAQjoTGhGXsoHtWe8LiiMEYIAQ3gdCzgIYgieKrC46AAjAmjD8oAAaYMAJlHhWK4k5w6WULYg+noj9tEilDA3d7Y6TUAHIAgAHdkEM0oFNwGg9AS1Aos-KEA)

Comment: polymorphic this - this is what I need, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change `equals(item: TestA)` and `equals(item:TestB)` to `equals(item : Observer)` in TestA class and TestB class.

Since Comparable type was given as Observable.

And in equals body you can cast observable object to TestA and compare its name property like below.

in TestA class.

```
class TestA implements Observer {
    private name = '';

    equals = (item: Observer) => {
        if(item instanceof TestA){
          return this.name === (item as TestA).name
        }
        return false
    }

    notify = () => {}
}
```

Comment: This does not fit, because I can do this: new TestA().equals(new TestB) and I won't get an error from typescript

Comment: can you explain what will not fit?

Comment: It'll fit beacuse when you do  new TestA().equals(new TestB) it will return false

Comment: I mean that the TS does not report an error in types, but I want to always be sure that I compare TestA with TestA and TestB with TestB

Comment: in that case, you have to change the design of interfaces and classes. with current design, you can't achieve that

Comment: because in your case TestA and TestB both implement Observable. that means TestA instanceof Observable and TestB instance is also instance of Observable

Comment: So you can compare them. and TS compiler is also happy about it